# WCF with transport security via certificates

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl

I want to secure my WCF service using client certificates, i.e. only client certificates from a specific root CA should be allowed to call my service.

For testing purposes I've created a single client certificate without a CA first. I registered the client certificate at the server's certificate store (under current user -> trusted people).

Within VS2013 I've enabled SSL on the WCF service project in order to have an HTTPS endpoint. I've adapted the following Web.config file of the service as follows:

```
<serviceCredentials>
  <clientCertificate>
    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
  </clientCertificate>
  ...
</serviceCredentials>

<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Furthermore I've adapted the App.config file of my client application as follows:

```
<clientCredentials>
  <clientCertificate findValue="Client" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
  <serviceCertificate>
    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
  </serviceCertificate>
</clientCredentials>

<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

However, this does not work, I get the following exception message:

*An error occurred while making the HTTP request to `https://localhost:44300/Service1.svc`. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.*

If I switch to message security (instead of transport security) and switch to the HTTP protocol everything seems to work just fine. So I guess I've missed some HTTPS-enabling step?! How to make transport security work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your certificate is not configured properly.Follow below steps

Copy the thumbprint of the certificate and run below command from command prompt in elevated mode

```
   netsh http add sslcert [Ipaddress:port] certhash=[thumbprint of certifcate] 
appid={unique id for application.you can use GUID for this]


[Ipaddress:port] Ipaddress and port
[thumbprint of certifcate]: thumbprint of certificate without spaces
appid :unique id you can use guid
```

**How to generate GUID from command prompt**

Open visual studio command prompt and run below command

**c:>uuidgen**

Comment: Thank you for your information, if I use this tool I get the simple error "The parameter is incorrect". Thumprint is without spaces, I used a new GUID (including dashes) as appId.

Comment: guid should be in curly braces

Comment: I've got `netsh http add sslcert ipport=localhost:44300 certhas=<thethumbprint> appid={22d80ae9-b4f7-4c41-b201-a34e2790b41e}`

Comment: replace ipport=localhost:44300 with 0.0.0.0:44300

Comment: Ok, I also had to change `certhas` to `certhash` ;-) However, still not working: `SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: run this netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300 and then rerun the above command

Comment: After successfully deleting the entry, I cannot recreate it, I receive the following error now: SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Comment: Check out this article for complete example http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2012/06/self-hosting-wcf-service-over-ssl.html