# WCF transport with https communication with certificates issue

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, ssl

I have a web application hosted in IIS on a server which communicates with a web service installed on the same server. The Web Service is installed as a standard service and not through IIS.

The service is up and running and i can navigate to it in browser using https. I added the certificate using netsh:
[WCF with transport security via certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281302/wcf-with-transport-security-via-certificates%20%22WCF%20with%20transport%20security%20via%20certifcates)

However when the web application tries to invoke calls to the web service i get the error on the following:

```
An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://TheServer/VehicleService/ConnectXml/1.0/https. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
```

I looked deeper into the error and i found this:

```
<ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.</Message>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
 <Message>The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.</Message>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the issue? Do i need to add any extra configuration to IIS?

I have tried adding the certificates locally and it works fine for me.

Comment: What is the URL of the server or domain?

Answer (score 0):

Your SecurityProtocolType may NOT be enabled (from Windows registry).
if you also get this:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection
```

Try one of the following protocol types:

```c#
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;   // Tls, Tls11, or Tls12
```